# Average Calculation not Working Well, Result is always NaN

Tags: javascript, api, binance

i was trying to do a calculation to find the average of the price from the array but i seem to be getting NaN, How do i solve it ?

```
var array = [ ];

var sum = 0;   
setInterval (function() { 
    fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHEUR')

    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        array = array.slice(0,10).concat([data.price]);
    });

    for (var number of array) {
        sum += number;
    }
    average = sum / array.length;
    console.log("Average of ETH/EUR every 10 seconds is: " +average);
    document.getElementById("avgStock").innerHTML= average; 



},10000);
```

[This is the result in the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtDDe.png)

Comment: It would be better if you console.log the data and array variable. See what's inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseFloat` to convert the return of the `string` coming from the API to `float`, so that you can so arithmetic operations.

```js
var array = [ ];

var t = setInterval (function() { 
    fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=ETHEUR')

    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        array = array.slice(0,10).concat([parseFloat(data.price)]);
    });

    const sum = array.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
    if(array.length == 0){
        console.log("Average of ETH/EUR every 10 seconds is: " +0);
        document.getElementById("avgStock").innerHTML= 0; 
    }
    else{
        average = sum / array.length;
        console.log("Average of ETH/EUR every 10 seconds is: " +average);
        document.getElementById("avgStock").innerHTML= average; 
    }

},10000);
```

Also, I updated the sum logic. It'll help you to calculate the sum in one line without running a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your `sum`
you're doing:

```js
for (var number of array) {
  sum += number;
}
```

but the number in the array is a string.

You need to parse the number first. There's a nifty shorthand, try this:

```js
for (var number of array) {
  sum += +number; //<- note the +number (parsing this to a number)
}
```

Or update the array:

```js
array = array.slice(0,10).concat([+data.price]); //<- added a + to parse the price
```

Ideally the data should be coming down from the API in the correct format.
I would advocate for fixing the API instead of parsing values

Answer (score 0):

I can see its printing the Average correctly first time, but giving NaN afterwards.

```
Average of ETH/EUR every 10 seconds is: 1682.39
Average of ETH/EUR every 10 seconds is: NaN
```

Please do console.log() for `data`, `array` and `sum`. If any of these values giving `null` or `NaN` that would be the issue to generate NaN for the Average.